# Python - Selenium in Ubuntu OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

After installing Selenium in Ubuntu and adding geckodriver to path I get this error when I run

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

What's going on?

EDIT: Solved using chromedriver instead of geckodriver.

Comment: Have you tried providing the path to geckodriver in your `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` line? It may just not find the driver.

Comment: @THeeren Do you mean like driver = webdriver.Firefox("/home/User/Downloads/wires") ?? I tried and get this error ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>",firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 78, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/User/Downloads/wires'`

Comment: At minimum you will need to provide the full path including the name of the driver. I am used the chromedriver. For the firefox driver you may need to create a profile first.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I tried with both chromedriver and geckodriver. I'm using ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 44):

Had the same problem. There were two ways to fix this for me:

Add executable_path arg in webdriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
```

And the second way its to add folder that contains geckodriver using export (only folder, not geckodriver):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/
```

Comment: Thanks @Poloq .. you saved my time 
this : 
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver') `

works for me...

Comment: this is weird, I did use the export option, and it didn't work, but specifying the `executable_path` in the python code worked...any ideas as to why?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have wasted more time. finally it worked.

Comment: very useful even after a year

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by @Poloq, the simplest way would be keeping your `geckodriver` binary in a directory which is already in your `PATH`.

```
mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```

This way you can avoid additional settings/configurations in your project with the downside of having an additional step when deploying on different systems.

Comment: Your answer is correct but you should write `cp`, not `mv`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you renamed "geckodriver" to "wires".

The solution is to add "geckodriver" to search path then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provided answers, there is also this option where you can  copy the driver to `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo cp geckodriver /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is available from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. To install selenium open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-selenium # for Python 2.x
```

and/or

```
sudo apt install python3-selenium # for Python 3.x
```

Then type python to start the Python interpreter and from selenium import webdriver should work like this:

```
$ python  
>>> from selenium import webdriver
```

Assuming that the path ~/.local/bin is in your execution PATH, here's how to install the Firefox webdriver, called geckodriver:

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.20.1/geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64.tar.gz
tar xvfz geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64.tar.gz
mv geckodriver ~/.local/bin
```

source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041541/i-want-to-install-selenium-webdriver-in-my-ubuntu-16-04-system-for-python