# how can i resolve this error in executing test.py?

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium, pytest, pytest-django

```
ERROR: test_register (login.tests.LoginTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/project/playlist/login/tests.py", line 19, in setUp
    self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/genv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/asif/Desktop/genv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.512s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I tried running this command:

```
$ ./manage.py test
```

Below is my test.py:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def views_login_user():
    pass


def test_login():
    views_login_user()




class LoginTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        super(LoginTestCase, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.quit()
        super(LoginTestCase, self).tearDown()

    def test_register(self):
        selenium = self.selenium
        #Opening the link we want to test
        selenium.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/register/')
        #find the form element
        username = selenium.find_element_by_id('id_username')
        email_address= selenium.find_element_by_id('id_email_address')
        password = selenium.find_element_by_id('id_password')

        submit = selenium.find_element_by_name('register')

        #Fill the form with data
        username.send_keys('gouthami')
        email_address.send_keys('gouth@gmail.com')
        password.send_keys('gouthu')


        #submitting the form
        submit.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        #check the returned result
        assert 'Check your email' in selenium.page_source
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40399367/3186190

Comment: @Cristián that's a good find. I guess first confirm that you HAVE the driver, and then try pointing to its path explicitly per Cristian's link. Seems like it's expecting the driver to be in default location that doesn't exist? Not sure why using chromedriver worked for the OP in that thread though...