# python script getting error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have new in python. i have install python on ubuntu 14.04 system.i have install selenium.webdriver.. but i have getting following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
  with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
  self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

I have try following code:

```
        from contextlib import closing
        from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
        from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from time import sleep
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import json

        url = "https://www.homedepot.ca/homedepotcacommercewebservices/v2/homedepotca/products/1000807160/localized/9999/"


        with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
             driver.get(url)
             sleep(3)
             Raw_data_buttom = browser.find_element_by_id("tab-1")
             Raw_data_buttom.click()
             soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
             data = json.loads( soup.find("pre", "data").get_text() )
             print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Firefox and geckodriver installed on your machine and available on PATH environment variable.

For more details, please see [Poloq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073548/python-selenium-in-ubuntu-oserror-errno-20-not-a-directory).