# NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/ghost/automation/pwd/geckodriver' with GeckoDrriver Firefox and Selenium using Python3

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

im using pycharm and my pythn

version 3.6.7 pip 9.0.1

and selenium version  selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.24.1

i install selenium using this commands

```
pip3 install selenium
```

then i code like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox("/home/ghost/automation/pwd/geckodriver")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("google.png")
driver.quit()
```

**when i run this i get this error **

```
/home/ghost/PycharmProjects/try/venv/bin/python /home/ghost/PycharmProjects/try/open/testcas1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ghost/PycharmProjects/try/open/testcas1.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox("/home/ghost/automation/pwd/geckodriver")
  File "/home/ghost/PycharmProjects/try/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "/home/ghost/PycharmProjects/try/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 80, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 309, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/ghost/automation/pwd/geckodriver'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and in this line  `driver = webdriver.Firefox("/home/ghost/automation/pwd/geckodriver")`  its correct path of my `geckodriver`  nd my **geckodriver
 version is 0.23.0**

these answers are not help to me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399367/8337986
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42945346/8337986

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### In Brief

Need to use the param key `executable_path`

### In Details

While working with *GeckoDriver*, *Firefox* and *Selenium*, you need to use the *Key* `executable_path` and the *Value* set to the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* within single quotes i.e. `'...'` with forward slash i.e. `/` as *path separator* as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/ghost/automation/pwd/geckodriver')
```

or use default location

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager(cache_valid_range=1).install())
```

Comment: @DebanjanB  `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash... and double quotes act the same as single quotes, so there's no need to prefer single.

Answer (score 0):

I just put the geckodriver.exe file to my main project folder and identified link as:
`driver=webdriver.Firefox("D:\Desktop\project")` without geckodriver, everything worked.

try whith

- "/home/ghost/automation/pwd"

or

- "\\home\\ghost\\automation\\pwd",
- "\home\ghost\automation\pwd"

if you using Atom IDE maybe your problem is you run a `.py` file with a script package. It's working not same as cmd console